# how to set a button's position randomly new?

Tags: java, android, button, random, time

when I click on the button 'start time', it sometimes moves completely out of the screen which is bad. and also, for me, the button is not placed randomly enough, sometimes on one click, it just moves a little downwards. And at the end instead of getting the time, the app stopps  with nullpointer. The Button should stay in the screen, placed randomly at a new place on click and after some clicks,  I want to recieve the elapsed time. why is this not working?

code:

```
@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_time);

    Random r = new Random();
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int screenWidth = decorView.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = decorView.getHeight();
      long startTime =  SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
      i++;
/*  
        Random r = new Random();

    int x = r.nextInt(R.id.wrap_content);
      int y = r.nextInt(R.id.wrap_content);




    b.setX(x);  
    b.setY(y);
     */ 

    if (i == 1 ) {

        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    if (i == 2 ) {
        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    if (i == 3 ) {
        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    if (i == 4 ) {
        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    if (i == 5 ) {
        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    if (i == 6 ) {
        start_time.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - start_time.getWidth()));
        start_time.setY(r.nextInt(screenHeight - start_time.getHeight()));
    }
    else if (i == 7) {
        long difference = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()  - startTime;

          Intent intent = new Intent(Game.this, MainScreen.class);
          intent.putExtra("time",difference);
         // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getIntent().getStringExtra("time"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          textview1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("time"));
        finish();
    }


}
```

and the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="chdfss.dsfwegg.trhhGame" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="139dp"
        android:text="Button" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please explain why you used 3 different ways to generate a random position

Comment: 1st time it was my own homebrew.. 
2nd time the screenedge was no border for the Button.
And after the newest  research this evening, I now am going to do it the easiest way I think it looks for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use margins.  That's the old way.  If you're supporting Android 3.0+, you can use View properties which will put them anywhere.

So something like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorVew();
int screenWidth = decorView.getWidth();
int screenHeight = decorView.getHeight();
...
// when you want to move the button.

view.setX(rand.nextInt(screenWidth - view.getWidth());
view.setY(rand.nextInt(screenHeight - view.getHeight());
```

The `View#setX()` and `View#setY()` methods are linked to the top left corner of the View.

If you want to support less then 3.0, then you can use the [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) animation api and animate with a time of 0 milliseconds so it's instant.

Comment: thank you. 2 problems now: `int screenWidth = getScreenWidth();` The method getScreenWidth() is undefined for the type Game :: and: `view.setX(r.nextInt(screenWidth - view.getWidth());` view cannot be resolved

Comment: getScreenWidth() and `view` are references you have to create.  You can find ways to get the full width in SO.  `view` is a reference to the view you want to move.

Comment: oh..no way thanks. either i'm too tired or too stupid lol. last question 2day:  1. The method getScreenWidth(int) is still undefined.. and 2. I can set the lenght and so at my own like `int screenWidth = getScreenWidth(900);` right?. But how to auto detect them? do I have to create a view with wrap_content?

Comment: Hello there sir. nice piece of code you brought to me. thank you. but the button sometimes just moves out of the screen... why? I thought the display was set? (updated code in qestion)

Comment: The coordinates are mapped to the container view so if the container view has any margins or anything, then you need to use the container view's width and height rather than the screen's width and height.

Comment: So I have to create a view in the xml? or how to get the containers height and length to the decorView?